# Sometimes the ActiveX Combobox only shows one row, why?

Tags: vba, excel, activex

It seems that when I first click on the combobox and then click on the arrow, all items are displayed.

While if I click on the arrow without clicking on the combobox before, only one item is displayed and I can click on scroll buttons to see the other items.

Why does this happen?

Here is the macro I am using to populate the combobox with items

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim selText As String
    selText = ComboBox1.selText
    ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each c In wConfig.Range("BudgetDropdown").Cells
        ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
    ComboBox1.selText = selText
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider using `ListFillRange` property of ComboBox. If you set it to `BudgetDropdown`, the list should populate automatically.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. However, ComboBox1.ListFillRange = wConfig.Range("BudgetDropdown") throws an error saying "Type mismatch"

Comment: You should use `ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "BudgetDropdown"`, or simply set it in property editor to `BudgetDropdown`. Just make sure the name is defined with workbook scope or it's in the same worksheet.

Comment: Great, that works and is a solution to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically populate combobox with data from named range, set it's `ListFillRange` property to the name of the range.

You can do it at runtime:

```
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "BudgetDropdown"
```

Or by setting it to `BudgetDropdown` in properties window.

Comment: There seems to be a downside with this. Every time a value is changed on the worksheet, the Combobox1_change event triggers. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/603076-combobox-change-event-triggers-value-change-worksheet.html

Comment: @user1283776 what is your definition of `BudgetDropdown` - is it volatile as in the linked thread?

Comment: It's a named range in Excel consisting of offset and counta functions. Maybe a better solution for me would be to remove all items for the combobox and then readd them like I was doing? But in my original code I have the problem that.clear seems to not only remove all items but also changes the value/text of the combobox which I don't want it to do. Is it possible to remove all items while leaving the value/text that is written in the combobox unaffected

Comment: I would start with replacing `OFFSET` volatile ranges, with construction like `=$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))` - this should eliminate unwanted change events.

Comment: I like the formula that you suggested and will use it in other situations in the future. But even with the new formula, combobox1_change isl triggered by some actions in the workbook. I can't use this solution for my intended purpose. I still appreciate you help and ideas!

Comment: @user1283776 OK, can you edit the question and describe in greater detail what is the purpose of this combobox, and what exactly does the Change event handler do? It would be great, if you could create a sample workbook to demonstrate current design and the issues.

Comment: I created a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617525/repopulate-a-combobox-itemlist-without-affecting-what-is-currently-written-insid/30617788#30617788 which would solve this problem for me. It would be great if you know an answer to that as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79521/discussion-between-user3964075-and-user1283776).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly why, but basically when you open a just-cleared-combobox it shows up only 1 lane because it "thinks" it is empty even if you have just refilled it. To trick it, you have to remove all the rows 1 by 1 till you reach your ListCount value (the number of rows your combobox will display). Then you can add all the new rows and after that you can delete the previously omitted rows. In my case i could not use the ListFillRange because my list was "embended" in several cells; so i had to extract it. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Combobox3_GotFocus()

Dim RngRange01 As Range 'Single cell where my row is "embended"
Dim IntCounter01 As Integer 'A counter
Dim BlnCheck as Boolean 'A boolean to remember me if it's the Combobox was empty before i
'focused it

IntCounter01 = ComboBox3.ListCount 'Set the counter equal to ListCount

'I check if the combobox is already filled or not and modify the BlnCheck
BlnCheck = True
If ComboBox3.ListCount = 0 Then BlnCheck = False

'In this For-Next i remove all the rows till i reach the ListRows
For IntCounter01 = IntCounter01 To ComboBox3.ListRows + 1 Step -1
    ComboBox3.RemoveItem IntCounter01 - 1
Next IntCounter01

'Set the range (it's a named list with titles located in another sheet)
Set RngRange01 = Sheets("MySheet1").Cells(2, Sheets("MySheet1").Range("MyList").Column)


Do Until RngRange01.Value = "" 'Cover the whole list

    'This If is to select the right data to insert (originally it was more complicated
    'so i've cut it for this explanation)
    If RngRange01.Offset(0, 1).Value <> RngRange01.Offset(-1, 1).Value Then
        ComboBox3.AddItem RngRange01.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If

    Set RngRange01 = RngRange01.Offset(1, 0) 'Next cell of the list
Loop

'Now we can remove the rows of the combobox we didn't remove previously (if the combobox 
'wasn't empty already)
If BlnCheck = True then
    For IntCounter01 = ComboBox3.ListRows To 1 Step -1
        ComboBox3.RemoveItem IntCounter01 - 1
    Next IntCounter01
End If

End Sub
```

So far it will work only after the really first time you focus the combobox. Still annoying! To completely remove (trick) the bug you have to add some lanes to the combobox before you focus it; perhaps when you open the workbook like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim IntCounter01 As Integer 'A counter

IntCounter01 = 1 'Set the counter

'In this For-Next we add a lane till we reach the ListRows
For IntCounter01 = IntCounter01 To Sheets("MySheet2").ComboBox3.ListRows
    Sheets("MySheet2").ComboBox3.AddItem ""
Next IntCounter01

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix that worked for me, it seems that you need to tell it what index it should be at before trying to assign items to it

```
Private Sub Top_GotFocus()
    Dim i As Integer
    MainProgram.InitVars        'Initializes the Varibles needed.--
    Sheets("Design").Top.Clear  'Clears the DropDown List.--
    Erase MainProgram.Tops()    'Clears the Tops array.--
    MainProgram.GetStdType "top", MainProgram.Tops(), "d", True  'Fills Array with all Tops found in "D# Standards" and sorts them alphabetically.--
    If MainProgram.IsArrayEmpty(MainProgram.Tops) = False Then 'If the tops array is NOT empty add the array items to the dropdown list.--
      Top.ListIndex = -1 '<------ (FIXED IT FOR ME)
      Sheets("Design").Top.List = MainProgram.Tops '(i), i  'Adds the tops(i) value to the Dropdown box.--
    End If
End Sub
```