# VBA: ComboBox only showing one item after Workbook_Open event

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am attempting to have a **`Workbook_Open`** event populate a controls ComboBox
so that when the user goes to the `Worksheet("Benchmarking")`, they have a pre-populated list to choose from that includes all the items in the array `datesArr`.

The problem i am having is, upon opening the spreadsheet and navigating to the `Worksheet("Benchmarking")`, i am only seeing one item in the drop down list:

[image: Current situation with ComboBox1]

If i select that item then the list actually populates:

[image: Full list appearing when selecting initial single item]

Desired result:

I want the full list to be available from the first time the user tries to make a selection not just after the `ComboBox1_Change` event is fired.

Having reviewed numerous post e.g. [Sometimes the ActiveX Combobox only shows one row, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613031/sometimes-the-activex-combobox-only-shows-one-row-why?answertab=votes#tab-top) , [Populating Combo Box on WorkBook Open](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/148586-populating-combo-box-workbook-open.html) I have tried several different approaches including the following in the `Workbook_Open` event code:

```
.ListFillRange = "DropDownDates"  
.List = DateArrToStrAr
```

I have also looped the array adding the items to ComboBox1. Each time i get the same 1 visible item in drop down result.

Is someone able to tell me where i am going wrong please?

My current code is

1) **ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Worksheets("Benchmarking").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
        .Clear
        .List = DateArrToStrArr '         
    End With

End Sub
```

2) **Worksheet("Benchmarking")**:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 'QH 2/11/17

     Dim datesArr() As String
     Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lkup")

     datesArr = DateArrToStrArr 'function that reads a named range of dates and converts to string to avoid dd/mm becoming mm/dd

     If ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Then ComboBox1.Value = "01/04/2016"

     ComboBox1.List = datesArr

     '.....other code

End Sub
```

Notes:

The array `datesArr` is populated by the function `DateArrToStrArr()` which reads in a named range of dates `"DropDownDates"` (workbook scope) and converts them to a string array. This is then assigned to the ComboBox.

`DropDownDates` is a dynamic named range with formula `=OFFSET(Lkup!$F$16,,,Lkup!$M$12,)`

Set-up: Excel 2016 64 bit Windows.

Comment: If it is controls box then you can set its `Input Range` property directly to `DropDownDates` and it will show the values. Is there any reason to do this programmatically?

Comment: I remember now why i was doing it programmatically. It was to ensure the combobox was populated with strings to avoid numbers or mm/dd/yyyy formatting appearing in the combobox. This ensured "dd/mm/yyyy" was always shown. The source range are dates before the function DateArrToStrArr() converts to string.

Comment: Are the dates in the Range `DropDownDates` fixed or calculated? If calculated, try forcing a recalc before using them.

Comment: The range is dynamic. Would a recalc not happen with the workbook open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CLR for making me think about recalcs. I decided to hack my way around this with the following:

I have added in `Worksheet("Benchmarking")` a **`Worksheet_Activate`** event and removed the Workbook_Open code. This seems to do the trick

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  ' ComboBox1.Clear
   ComboBox1.List = DateArrToStrArr
End Sub
```