# Sometimes the form Combobox only shows one row, why?

Tags: excel, combobox, form-control, vba

I have copied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613031/sometimes-the-activex-combobox-only-shows-one-row-why) topic because it is a very similar issue that appears in my form.

I have a form in which one of the combo boxes performs a search in the list of items on every keystroke. The issue is that the list of the results shown at the moment of typing is only 1 row, shown below the combo box. On the righthand side of the field, there is an up/down arrow scroll button.

[image]

If I use it to scroll through the list it shows the found items. When I click on the arrow of the combo box the field with the results disappear and if I click once again on the arrow it shows the full list of the results from the performed search.

[image]

Here is the code of the routine:

```
Private Sub MiscD_Change()
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long
    With Me.MiscD
        If .Value <> "" And .ListIndex = -1 Then
            v = Range("MiscD").Value
            .Clear  'clear all items

    'Repopulate with matched items
            For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                If LCase(v(i, 1)) Like "*" & LCase(.Value) & "*" Then
                    .AddItem v(i, 1)
                    .DropDown
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            'Repopulate with all items
            .List = Range("MiscD").Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

It seems that ListFillRange is not available in FormControl.
I've checked for .DropDown properties that might force the results to be shown, but I couldn't find any.

Something else I've noticed is that selecting by the arrow keys from the keyboard is going through the original list while selecting by clicking with the mouse gives you the list of the items from the search.

I think that there are two lists, but I do not know where the list of the items from the search is stored so I can address it somehow.

Comment: Thanks, Hexfire, I was just looking for a way to show the images.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution

I've found that the .DropDown is implemented after each cycle and stays only one row for some reason that I do not know.

What I did is I've moved it after the For cycle thus all the values have been checked and the list can be shown at full

Here is the code

```
Private Sub MiscD_Change()
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long
    With Me.MiscD
        If .Value <> "" And .ListIndex = -1 Then
            v = Range("MiscD").Value
            .Clear  'clear all items
            MiscDe.SetFocus
            MiscD.SetFocus

    'Repopulate with matched items
            For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                If LCase(v(i, 1)) Like "*" & LCase(.Value) & "*" Then
                    .AddItem v(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
            .DropDown
        Else
            'Repopulate with all items
            .List = Range("MiscD").Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I use SetFocus to hide and show the dropdown field when I change the search criteria in the combo box.

This is a bit clumsy, so if someone can think of a better way it will be helpful.